# How to access slider data in reactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a javascript file which initializes a slider on page loading

**Slider.JS**

```
$('.priceSlider')
        .slider(
            {
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 2000000,
                values: [500000, 1500000],
                step: 10000, ...
```

**React**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
 componentDidMount() {
        this.loadScript('Slider.js');
}
```

in the console I can access the values using  `console.log($('.priceSlider').slider("values"));`
but when I try to use in react like below ...

```
   handleChange(e) {
            console.log($('.priceSlider').slider("values"));}
```

but it throws the error

```
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...)(...).slider is not a function
```

Comment: You may want to add a `jquery` label

Comment: seems you have a global instance of jquery try console logging using that. ` `console.log(window.$('.priceSlider').slider("values"));`